# In Automation Testing , I can launch the browser but cannot launch the url

Tags: automation

In Automation Testing , I can launch the browser but cannot launch the url  using selenium IDE .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLq9Z.png)

I verified there is no extra chromewebdriver instance is  available .

Someone please check my code and advise